# Click a single value dropdown button in a website using xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to change the dropdown to the DC innings in this image attached below and I am using the following code through which I am able to open the dropdown. All I need is toggle and select the DC innings in dropdown and would need to know what is wrong with my current code as I an unable to click. the url is
https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/ipl-2020-21-1210595/delhi-capitals-vs-mumbai-indians-final-1237181/ball-by-ball-commentary

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='comment-container-head']/div"))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'ci-dd__menu')]/div[contains(@class, 'ci-dd__selected-option') and text()='DC Innings']"))).click()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath was off nothing came up with that one. It's also a span tag not a div tag. You could instead do if you want to be retrictive to the menu //div[@class='ci-dd__menu']//span[.='DC Innings']

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get('https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/ipl-2020-21-1210595/delhi-capitals-vs-mumbai-indians-final-1237181/ball-by-ball-commentary')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='comment-container-head']/div"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[.='DC Innings']"))).click()
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. yes wanted to be restrictive to the menu..it works now